# Необходимо вернуть пользователя с наибольшим кол-вом заказов .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ef

Есть две связанные сущности User и Order:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; } 

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public UserStatus Status { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Как найти и асинхронно вернуть такого пользователя?

```
public Task<User> GetUser()
    {
        ???
    }
```

Comment: **var user = _dbContext.Orders
    .GroupBy(o => o.UserId)
    .Select(o => new { UserId = o.Key, OrderCount = o.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(o  => o.OrderCount)
    .FirstOrDefault();**

Comment: Нужно вернуть именно юзера, не анонимный тип данных, или все же такое невозможно?

Comment: Напиши второй запрос, и найдите этого юзера по id который должен быть в анонимном типе

Comment: точно, все так гениально и просто, спасибо большое!

Comment: `.Orders.GroupBy(order => order.UserId).MaxBy(g => g.Count()).First().User`

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что такое "юзер с макс.кол-вом заказов". Пример: Есть Вася у него 100 заказов, есть Петя у него тоже 100 заказов. Гонг-вопрос: Какой из этих юзеров имеют максимальное кол-во заказов?